# Clans, Immortals... Is there a manual for this stuff?

Tags: clicker-heroes

I just joined a clan with my friend and we were in steam voice chat together when we clicked "Fight" on "Today's Raid". We got a screen with an immortal, there was a timer and a damage bar that wasn't moving. I went to try and check my heroes, that didn't work, same with my relics. So I asked my friend what's happening, he said he already killed it 5 times, but I saw nothing. We were both confused as to what was going on. Since I'm an idle player I confirmed that I still had idle DPS, I did. Then the timer ran out.

The results then showed me that I had not defeated the level one immortal, I had a 1h countdown to retry. My friend said his screen showed he had, and he got 6 hero souls (totally not worth the 1M hs 50 rubies are otherwise worth). He had a 23h countdown to try again.

Then I clicked the refresh button; because that was really required when I was joining his clan. Finally it showed that I had defeated the immortal, and rewarded me 1 hero soul. It did not show a retry counter and instead showed the same counter to try again for tomorrow's raid. Also it showed my 0 damage vs his 500k damage.

Well... I would say "what the" here. I need a manual for this part of the game. There was no indication of what to expect, what to do, nor of why we were doing this? I assume at some point, hopefully in a few days, we'd be earning more hero souls than the 50 rubies are worth, but without a formula or instructions I can't guess when that might be.

Does anyone have a simple cogent way to explain what clans are, how you do "Today's Raid", what you should be prepared for going in, and what outcomes you can expect?

Comment: thre is no idle dmg in immortal fights? You should be grateful, i cannot even join a clan. It is bugged.

Comment: @NukesPlus I was on live chat while joining the clan. There seems to be a bug, but it's not insurmountable. Friend makes a clan with 50 rubies and a unique name. You search that name (case sensitive) and join it. You will see that your request to join is pending (even after the friend has accepted you). Don't click wait more or all UI will disappear (restart clicker heroes if so). Instead click refresh, and you will see that you've been accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, check it out : [Clans FAQ on ClickerHeroes Wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/wiki/faqclans)

Basically, you deal click-only dommage (*Immortal dommage*) to a special kind of boss. Each click, you deal 1 immortal dommage per primal boss you killed during your game. Standard DPS does not apply.

When you beat him, you gain Heroes Souls, based on the dommage you inflicted. If you fail, you can try again a number of times for free, then for rubies (it will stack the dommage).

The manual really says it all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no idle damage in an Immortal fight. The damage you deal to the the Immortal is 1 damage for every hero soul gained from primal bosses. You deal this amount of damage every time you click, you have 30 seconds to click madly and during this time you cannot go to other tabs or fight normal monsters.

When the Time ends, all damage dealt to the Immortal will stay, and if you click "Today's Raid" and then the little scroll, you can see the total damage you have done to the Immortal. Once sufficient damage has been dealt to kill the immortal, you will no longer be able to fight the immortal, but you will be able to collect an amount of hero souls for defeating it.

Anyone in your clan can attack the mortal, and there will be a 1 hour cool down for doing so. You will get more hero souls the more damage you deal to it and people who do not participate will still get some HS, yet less that those who damaged the Immortal.

The Immortal resets for every day and if you can't defeat it, it will go down one level. If you do defeat it it will go up by one level. The level dictates how much health the immortal has and how many HS it yields.

Sources:

- Personal Experience
- Wiki Page [http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Clans]

Answer (score 0):

Especially in the early levels those immortal fights can be confusing, took me while of reading to get what was happening.

For every day there is one immortal that everyone can fight up to 3 times in 1 hour intervals (you 3 times and your friend 3 times), once the immortal is defeated the souls are awarded according to the level of the immortal, so if you get higher the amount of hero souls will increase a lot. There wont be any more fights happening that day.

What you experienced is overkilling. If you deafeat an immortal in the first fight you can keep hitting the next level until your timer runs out. This can even happen multiple times so you dont hold yourself up several days on lower levels. Here as well, no more fight till the next day. E.g. you said you get 1M hs from an ascension, the base life of immortals 1000 and it multiplies by 2 every level so you should get to somewhere around 30 gaining you half a million hs but it would take a whole month without that mechanic.